# What are the advantages of using adapter, helper for creating or accessing database?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

Currntly i am creating SQLite database in android using following code:

```
    SQLiteDatabase db;
try{
            SQLiteDatabase  dbe = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase("/data/data/bangla.rana.fahim/databases/dictionary", null,0);
            dbe.close();
   }
            catch(SQLiteException e){

                db = openOrCreateDatabase("dictionary", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
                db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS LIST(wlist varchar,ex varchar);");                
                db.close();
            }
```

And retrieving data using cursor like:

```
  Cursor cc = db.rawQuery(q, null);//q is the desired query.
```

But i have seen many example of using helper and adapters for the very same purpose. So, my question is what are the benefits of using them?

Answer (score 3):

I guess you are referring to `SQLiteOpenHelper`, the documentation is pretty clear:

> A helper class to manage database creation and version management.
>
> You create a subclass implementing onCreate(SQLiteDatabase),
>   onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase, int, int) and optionally
>   onOpen(SQLiteDatabase), and this class takes care of opening the
>   database if it exists, creating it if it does not, and upgrading it as
>   necessary. Transactions are used to make sure the database is always
>   in a sensible state.

With this you don't have to *manually* create your database and take care of upgrading it. You just have to implement the two methods `onCreate()` and `onUpgrade()` with your database logic and android will make sure to call this methods when is needed. I don't know at what are you referring when you say adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Well it is more concerned about software desing patters. In the SQLiteOpenHelper you do the tasks more related with creating and updating the database when user installs the app or in a db version change.

In an Adapter class which holds the previous class you usually hold a reference to the db and you have the methods to actually interact with it doing the different kind of queries (selects, inserts...).

This way you have you code well encapsulated and therefore it is much easier to maintain.